# How to test UI interaction of Silverlight dialogs?

Tags: silverlight, dialog, silverlight-toolkit

I am using Silverlight 3.0 Unit Testing, version Silverlight Toolkit November 2009.

Apart from unit tests, it allows to do UI interaction tests, typically using  AutomationPeer subclasses (eg ButtonAutomationPeer to interact with a Button).

Are there AutomationPeer classes to test the interaction with the following:

- OpenFileDialog
- SaveFileDialog
- MessageBox

In unit tests it would be possible to stub these, but for integration and browser testing it would be great to have this testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I know.

This is a difficult one to automate because these user interactions happen in operating system dialogs, not in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible; you can use the White testing framework to do it.  See [this thread](http://white.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=204953) on the White discussion forum for instructions.